# Powershell Find specific row (querying) psobject

Tags: powershell, psobject

I'm new to Powershell. And I'm struggling with the most simplest of tasks.

OK.  This is a really stupid question, but I have created a PSObject ... added members (4 columns, ID, Name, Status, TagFile; a number of rows) ... I have a loop ... for each i (iteration) ... I want it to use the values for the row in my object where ID = i.

It's really not hard.  I have googled and haven't come up with an answer which is clear enough or concise enough to help me.

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood your question. If I am right, I understand that you want to store the value into the column. For that you may use $object_name.ID = i

Comment: Add your actual code and an example of what you wnat to achieve.

Comment: Foolishly I am at work and my code is on my laptop at home.  All I want to do is query my object.  I want to find the row in my object where obj.ID = 1 etc.

Answer (score 1):

this returns the row where the ID value is 1

```
$myPSObject | ? { $_.id -eq 1 }
```

From there you can tune the query based on your necessity